# Compare two arrays and create third one

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have two arrays that I tried to compare and create third one

my first array:

```
sevenDays = ["04","05","06","07","08","09","10"];
```

my second array:

```
   json[0] =  [Object{day="04",value="5"}, Object { day="05",value="8"}, Object { day="09",value="9"}]
```

what I am trying to get is:

```
 [[04,5],[05,8],[06,0],[07,0],[08,0],[09,9],[10,0]]
```

I tried like this

```
var desiredArray= [];                           
$.each(sevenDays, function (i, v) {
   val= 0;
     if (json[0][i].value) val = json[0][i].value;
     desiredArray[i] = [v, val]
}); 


 [[04,5],[05,8],[06,9],[07,0],[08,0],[09,0],[10,0]] //output
```

Comment: you should create a http://jsfiddle.net/ for easy testing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're currently comparing the value from index `i` in `sevenDays` to the `value` property of the object at index `i` of `json[0]`, but that's not correct because the order doesn't match up. The value for `09` is at index 2 in `json[0]` but `09` is at index 5 in `sevenDays`.

You'll need to iterate over `sevenDays`, and for each iteration iterate over `json[0]` to find the matching object, like so:

```
var desiredArray = [];

$.each(sevenDays, function (i, day) {
    val = 0;
    $.each(json[0], function(j, value) {
        if(day == value.day)
            val = value.value;
    });
    desiredArray[i] = [day, val];
});
```

Take a look at [this working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F56KY/).

Comment: I got it now :). thank you very much! (each in each should't be a problem?)

Comment: @InTry Nested `each` functions aren't going to cause issues, provided you pick unique variable names to avoid shadowing.

Answer (score 0):

considering your second array in proper json format ....

you can do it like this

```
var data[] =["",""]
for(value in sevenDays)
{
for(Object in json[0])
{
if(Object.hasOwnProperty(data[value])
{
     // do ur stuff here :)
}
else
{
     //do the other stuff here :)
}
}
}
```

Comment: The `for(x in y)` syntax is for iterating over properties of objects, not over arrays.